# Saving Dragged and Dropped Item Positions in Local Storage for Persistent Display

Tags: javascript, user-interface, frontend, drag-and-drop, local-storage

```js
const titleElement = document.querySelector('.js-title');
const messageElement = document.querySelector('.js-message');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.js-add-button');
const ulList = document.querySelector('.js-sortable-list');

let draggedItem = null;
let initialMouseY = null;

addBtn.addEventListener('click', addTodo);

let todoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoList')) || [];

createTodoList();

function createTodoList() {
    ulList.innerHTML = '';

    if (todoList.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    todoList.forEach((todoObject, index) => {
        const { title, message } = todoObject;
        const todoItem = document.createElement('li');
        todoItem.draggable = "true";
        todoItem.classList.add('listItem')

        todoItem.innerHTML = `<div class="js-todo-item draggable">
                                <h1 class="js-h1-title">${title}</h1>
                                <p class="js-p-message">${message}</p>
                                <div class="js-buttons-parent">
                                    <input class="js-checkbox" type="checkbox">
                                    <button class="js-delete-button">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;

        ulList.append(todoItem);
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('.listItem').forEach((draggableItem, index) => {
        draggableItem.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
            draggedItem = draggableItem;
            initialMouseY = event.clientY;
            setTimeout(() => draggedItem.classList.add('dragging'), 0);
        });
        draggableItem.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
            draggedItem.classList.remove('dragging');
        });
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('.js-delete-button')
        .forEach((deleteBtn, index) => {
            deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this task?')) {
                    deleteTodo(index);
                }
            });
        });
}

function deleteTodo(index) {
    todoList.splice(index, 1);
    saveLocalStorage();
    createTodoList();
}

ulList.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target;

    if (draggedItem && target !== draggedItem && target.parentElement === ulList) {
        const mouseY = e.clientY;
        const targetRect = target.getBoundingClientRect();

        const adjustment = initialMouseY < mouseY ? 0 : targetRect.height;

        const isTopHalf = mouseY < targetRect.top + adjustment;

        if (isTopHalf) {
            ulList.insertBefore(draggedItem, target);
        } else {
            ulList.insertBefore(draggedItem, target.nextElementSibling);
        }
    }
    
    
});

// ... Your existing code ...

ulList.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
    if (draggedItem) {
        draggedItem.classList.remove('dragging');
        saveLocalStorage();
        draggedItem = null;
        initialMouseY = null;
        
    }
});

// ... Your existing code ...



// ... Your existing code ...


ulList.addEventListener('dragenter', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

});

function addTodo() {
    const title = titleElement.value;
    const message = messageElement.value;

    if (title.trim() === '') {
        alert('Please fill the title');
        return;
    } else if (message.trim() === '') {
        alert('Please fill the message');
        return;
    }

    todoList.push({ title, message });
    saveLocalStorage();

    createTodoList();
    titleElement.value = '';
    messageElement.value = '';
}

function saveLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(todoList));
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #a2a8d3;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 350px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.js-form{
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.js-form > *{
    padding: 7px;
    width: 350px;
    /* border-radius: 10px; */
}

.js-message {
    resize: none;
}

.js-sortable-list {
    margin-top : 5px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.js-sortable-list li {
    background-color: #5585b5;
    margin-top: 10px;
    /* border: 2px solid #334ce3; */
    border-radius: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
    
}

.js-todo-item {
    color: #333;
    margin: 20px;
}

.draggable > * {
    margin:  10px ;
}

.listItem.dragging :where(.js-todo-item) {
    opacity: 0;
}

.js-delete-button {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #113f67;
    color: #e7eaf6;
    font-size: 17px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.invisible {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
}

.js-buttons-parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 30px;;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="js-form">
            <input type="text" class="js-title" placeholder="Title">
            <textarea name="" id="" cols="20" rows="5" class="js-message" placeholder="Your task"></textarea>
            <button class="js-add-button">Add</button>
        </div>
       
        <ul class="js-sortable-list">
        </ul>
    </div>

    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm working on a web application where I have implemented drag-and-drop functionality for a list of items. I want to be able to save the positions of these items in local storage so that they retain their positions even after the page is refreshed.

I have attempted to implement this feature, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's a simplified version of my code:

I'm looking for guidance on how to correctly save and retrieve the positions of dragged and dropped items in local storage so that they stay at their last remembered positions after a page refresh.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I have noticed that localStorage does not work on this page(Stackoverflow). But you can easily add new task and they are automatically saved in localStorage, you can also sort them by drag and drop events. However i cannot save the new positions in localStorage. Many thanks!

Comment: Moreover, I have not found anything through the Internet about this kind of feature. Looks like it is not common what I want to achieve. Although I believe that there is a way  to do it without any libraries or frameworks. Any tips would be appreciated